# Intellij VIM mode, bookmarks across editors

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I can use (ma) to bookmark the current position under (a). I can then jump back to us using ('a). However if I have two files open, I would have thought that when I have an upper case bookmark (mA), if I then in the other editor I jump to boomark (A) using ('A), that I would be taken to the editor that owns that bookmark, but it doesn't. In Eclipse it does this. Surely IDEA can be convinced to jump across editors using bookmarks?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue that is likely to be fixed soon. Feel free to vote for [VIM-523](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-523).